# Calculate the mean of one column across multiple .csv files How?

Tags: r

I am newbie in R and have got to calculate the mean of column `sulf` from 332 files. The mean formulas bellow works well with 1 file . The problem comes when I attempt to calculate across the files.

Perhaps the reading all files and storing them in `mydata` does not work well? Could you help me out?

Many thanks

```
pollutantmean <- function(specdata,pollutant=xor(sulf,nit),i=1:332){
            specdata<-getwd()
            pollutant<-c(sulf,nit)

            for(i in 1:332){
               mydata<-read.csv(file_list[i])
            }


            sulfate <- (subset(mydata,select=c("sulfate")))
            sulf <- sulfate[!is.na(sulfate)]
            y <- mean(sulf)


       print(y) 


     }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Calculate the mean for each file separately and store it in a vector, calculate the mean for _all_files...?

Comment: @bouncyball I believe the latter is true. The tools to use here are `list.files` and `lapply`/`sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but the steps are as followed. Note also that this kind of questions are being asked over and over again (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r)). Try searching for "work on multiple files", "batch processing", "import many files" or something akin to this.

```
lx <- list.files(pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

# gives you a list of 
xy <- sapply(lx, FUN = function(x) {
  out <- read.csv(x)
  out <- out[, "sulfate", drop = FALSE] # do not drop to vector just for fun
  out <- out[is.na(out[, "sulfate"]), ]
  out
  }, simplify = FALSE)

xy <- do.call(rbind, xy) # combine the result for all files into one big data.frame
mean(xy[, "sulfate"]) # calculate the mean
# or
summary(xy)
```

If you are short on RAM, this can be optimized a bit.

Comment: Why `sapply` with *simplify = FALSE*? Why not just call `lapply`?

Comment: @Parfait personal choice, no reason.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.

I have sorted it out. the key was to use full.names=TRUE in list.files and  rbind(mydata, ... ) as otherwise it reads the files one by one and does not append them after each other, which is my aim

See below. I am not sure if it is the most "R" solution but it works

```
       pollutantmean<-function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332){
         files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)   
         mydata <- data.frame()
            for (i in id) {                                
            mydata <- rbind(mydata, read.csv(files_list[i]))
            }


              if(pollutant %in% "sulfate")
                 {
                  mean(mydata$sulfate,na.rm=TRUE)

                   }
               else
                 {if(pollutant %in% "nitrate")
            {
            mean(mydata$nitrate,na.rm=TRUE)
            }
           else
            {"wrong pollutant"  
            }  
          }
         }
```

`